# Buttons value to EditText?

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

I have an EditText and buttons like phone caller numbers I putted on every button to setText on editText but why not writing on next each other..?
when i Press one then 2 the whole edit text is just 2 then if i clicked 3 the 2 deleted and 3 wroten i want to be like keyboard to text on next each other

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText phoneTo;
    Button btn,btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5,btn6,btn7,btn8,btn9,btn10,btn11,btn12,btn99;
    TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        phoneTo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        btn5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        btn6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn6);
        btn7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn7);
        btn8 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn8);
        btn9 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn9);
        btn10 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn10);
        btn11 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn11);
        btn12 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn12);
        btn99 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn99);
        phoneTo.setSelection(phoneTo.getText().length());



       btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                makePhoneCall(view);
            }
        });


    }

    public void makePhoneCall(View view) {

        try {
            String number = phoneTo.getText().toString();
            Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;
            }
            startActivity(phoneIntent);


        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Call failed, please try again later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btn1:
                phoneTo.setText("1");
                break;
            case R.id.btn2:
                phoneTo.setText("2");
                break;
            case R.id.btn3:
                phoneTo.setText("3");
                break;
            case R.id.btn4:
                phoneTo.setText("4");
                break;
            case R.id.btn5:
                phoneTo.setText("5");
                break;
            case R.id.btn6:
                phoneTo.setText("6");
                break;
            case R.id.btn7:
                phoneTo.setText("7");
                break;
            case R.id.btn8:
                phoneTo.setText("8");
                break;
            case R.id.btn9:
                phoneTo.setText("9");
                break;
            case R.id.btn10:
                phoneTo.setText("0");
                break;
            case R.id.btn11:
                phoneTo.setText("*");
                break;
            case R.id.btn12:
                phoneTo.setText("#");
                break;
            case R.id.btn99:
                String str=phoneTo.getText().toString();
                if (str.length() >1 ) {
                    str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
                    phoneTo.setText(str);
                }
                else if (str.length() <=1 ) {
                    phoneTo.setText("");
                }
                break;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to append those typed characters in string rather then placing it on the edittext directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your switch statement is wrong, if I got what you are asking for.

You want to make the user write a full number, but you are using everytime the

```
phoneTo.setText(number);
```

this means everytime the edittext will be resetted with the `number` value

Use instead `phoneTo.append(mynumber);`

hope it helped

Comment: @Dr.Easy welcome :) Just another question: why are you passing the `View view` to the `makePhoneCall` method if you are not using it?

Comment: i don't to do inputtype= phone so i needed when i press on my custom buttons appears on edit text then with call button make a call
thanks anyways it done.!

Answer (score 0):

You have to append strings

try like this

```
   case R.id.btn1:
          String str=phoneTo.getText().toString()+"1";
         phoneTo.setText(str);
        break;
```

similarly for all cases

Answer (score 0):

With SetText() you are changing whole text in EditText, you have to concate the current text with the input:

```
phoneTo.setText(phoneTo.getText() + "1");
```

Or take a look to functions like getText().append(), getText().insert(), getText().replace()

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this because the way you did you were just replacing the EditText with the number everytime.

`

> ```
> @Override
> public void onClick(View v) {
>
>     switch (v.getId()){
>         case R.id.btn1:
>             String number = phoneTo.getText.toString();
> number += "1";
> phoneTo.setText(number);
> break;
>         ...
>         case R.id.btn99:
>             String str=phoneTo.getText().toString();
>             if (str.length() >1 ) {
>                 str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
>                 phoneTo.setText(str);
>             }
>             else if (str.length() <=1 ) {
>                 phoneTo.setText("");
>             }
>             break;
>
>     }
> ```

`